# Print a Connect 4 grid based on some rules for each cell

Tags: functional-programming, formatting, scala, ascii-art, connect-four

In a game of Connect4:

- we start with an empty grid
- two players place pieces X and O on the grid
- the first player to achieve 4 pieces in a line wins!
- this is a text based console game

Here is the code I wrote to print each cell in the grid:

```
def asText(grid: Grid) = {

      def asText(x:Int, y:Int) = {

        val isTop = y == 0 && x != grid.x + 1 && x != 0
        val newLine = x == grid.x + 1
        val isBottom = y == grid.y + 1 && x != 0
        val isLeft = x == 0
        val isX = grid.pieces.contains(Piece("X", x,y))
        val isY = grid.pieces.contains(Piece("O", x,y))

        List(isTop, newLine, isBottom, isLeft, isX, isY) match {
          case true::_ => "-"
          case _::true::_ => "|\n"
          case _::_::true::_ => "-"
          case _::_::_::true::_ => "|"
          case _::_::_::_::true::_ => "X"
          case _::_::_::_::_::true::_ => "O"
          case _ => "."
        }
      }

      val v = for {
        y  <- 0 to grid.y + 1
        x  <- 0 to grid.x + 1
        text = asText(x, y)
      } yield text

      v.mkString("")
    }
```

**I don't like this** `_::_::_::_::_::true::_` **but can't think of a way to improve it. Can this style be improved? Is there a more Scala idiomatic style to do this?**

Example output:

```
|------|
|XO....|
|......|
|......|
|......|
|......|
|......|
|......|
|------|
```

Edit: As requested

```
case class Piece(symbol:String, x:Int, y:Int)
case class Grid(x:Int = 6, y:Int = 7, pieces:List[Piece] = List())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the graphic representation of a data structure an integral part of that data structure (`val gString = myGrid.asText`) or separate and independent from the data structure (`val gString = asText(myGrid)`)?

I tend to favor the former, but if the `Grid` API is solid and supplies everything needed for one or more graphic representations, then the latter is probably the better choice. It's a little hard to judge here as you haven't provided the `Grid` (or `Piece`) code.

I question the choice of iterating through coordinates that *are known* to be outside the `Grid` just for the purpose of drawing a border. Wouldn't it be easier to get the grid contents and simply "wrap" them with border characters?

```
def asText(grid :Grid) :String = {
  val border = "|" + "-"*grid.x + "|"
  (1 to grid.y).map{ y =>
    (1 to grid.x).map{ x =>
      if      (grid.pieces.contains(Piece("X", x, y))) "X"
      else if (grid.pieces.contains(Piece("O", x, y))) "O"
      else "."
    }.mkString("|", "", "|")
  }.mkString(s"$border\n", "\n", s"\n$border")
}
```

Comment: To answer your question: object Connect4Game {
    def asText(grid :Grid): String = { ... }